# Regular expression group syntax

Tags: python, regex, parsing, grouping

I am currently writing a python script to parse information from a text file using regular expressions. The data is presented as can be found in the following link: https://regex101.com/r/fa4XTi/3

As you can see the value listed under each attribute can either be a single line or multiple lines. My script is taking each attribute and value and putting it in a dictionary as {attribute:value}.

This issue I am having is my regex "or" statement is assigning the groups in a way I was not expecting. The attributes with the multiline values are being made into additional groups under the previous attribute.

```
    ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME="THING1" 
  {
    VALUE { CV="SOME_AMOUNT" }
  }
  ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME="UNIT"
  {
    VALUE
    {
      SET="SS_VESSEL"
      STRING_VALUE="WATER_STORAGE"
      CHANGEABLE=F
    }
  }
```

Unit and its value is being made into groups 3 and 4 of the previous match rather than making them groups 1 and 2 under their own match.

The regular expression I am using is:

```
r"ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME=\"(.*)\"\n\s+{\n\s+VALUE\s+{\s+(.*)}|ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME=\"(.*)\"\n\s+{\n\s+VALUE\s+{\s+(.*\n\s+.*\n\s+.*)\n\s+}"
```

What am I doing wrong with my pattern?

Comment: What about [`ATTRIBUTE_INSTANCE NAME="([^"]*)"\s+{\s+VALUE\s+{\s+([^}]*)\s+}`](https://regex101.com/r/fa4XTi/4)?

Comment: Capture groups are counted left to right. `|` does not reset the count. With your regex multi-line values will always be capture groups 3 and 4. Or did i misunderstand your question?

Comment: Thanks, ctwheels! That worked.

Comment: No, you got my question, rici. I am not so well versed in regex and did not know that | did not reset the count. I added ctwheels pattern into my script and now it is parsing as intended.